# Build error "Cannot find name 'Record'" with bootstrap 4

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

Today, I decided to migrate my ASP .NET MVC 5 project from bootstrap 3 to bootstrap 4 (the sass version).

After the migration, I got an error after the compilation of my project.

> Error Build:Cannot find name 'Record'.
>   Error Build:Cannot find name 'undefined'.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

After some research, I found this link to have a better understanding of typescript and visual studio. If you want to improve your skills, you can go to [this official page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript) and have some readings.

**The solution**
You just have to update the typescript plugin for Visual studio. You can download the latest version [here for visual studio 2015.](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=48593)

[Here for visual studio 2017](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258)

Enjoy!

Comment: If you plan on having both version depending on your layout, be careful of the version of the javascript file (and your browser may keep the wrong file in cache). You might face some problem with the menu when collapsed.

Comment: Daniel, my menu is stacked. What js file are you referring to be careful about with respect to the version? How did you fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

If, for some reason you are unable to update your Visual Studio with the updated TypeScript .exe file (company/business IT policy, non-admin account, etc...), you can try this solution:

1. Single-click on the "index.d.ts" file in Visual Studio Solution Explorer.
2. Look in the Properties panel, under "Build Action".
3. Switch it from "TypeScriptCompile" to "Content".

Now, you'll be able to build your project without these errors.

**Update 2019**
I have found another workaround/solution that hasn't had any noticeable effects and still allows me to compile without erroring on *index.d.ts*. Just comment line 68 in your index.d.ts file as such:

```
//[name: string]: (BaseModifier & Record<string, any>) | undefined;
```

Comment: What's the downside with this, can you not debug certain aspects or what?

Comment: @Snoop - that I haven't figured out, to be honest. I just was messing around at work trying to get this to work because we us dev's are in a very restrictive work environment, but haven't encountered an issue with anything I've done, doing it this way. However, I did figure out another solution (I'll update my answer with the other option).

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2015:

I downloaded [TypeScript](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593), installed and restarted Visual Studio. While restarting it prompted me the TypeScript my solution uses is older than what is installed(2.9.2) and whether I want to update it to the supported version, I clicked Yes and that fixed the issue.

My guess is TypeScript 2.9.2 is for VS 2017 maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled jpopper.cs and went to the Web.config file and added these lines of code

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

to deal with that validation error.

Comment: sorry this is the first time I have submitted code and I think I might have messed it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, for me it has been fixed by update VS 17 to latest version!!

Answer (score -1):

- open your project in visual studio 2017 and it will ask you to upgrade the typescript just press upgrade

  ### OR

### Upgrade your Typescript version