# Cannot find name 'Record' in index.d.ts build error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, fullcalendar

I ran into an `The index is outside the matrix limits.` error while adding a bundle to my bundleConfig while following [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKU5omv8X3s) tutorial about the `fullCalendar` jQuery plugin

these are the bundles. The files are a little bit different than the ones in the tutorial because of newer versions. **note: I also tried the older versions after getting the errors**

```
        //Calendar css
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/fullcalendarcss").Include(
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css",
            "~/Content/fullcalendar.css"));

        //Calendar script
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/fullcalendarjs").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/moment.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js"));
```

while googling for a fix for the error, I came upon [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809904/stylebundle-index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array) stackoverflow page where the fix was to update the packages. so I did and got the following errors:

`Cannot find *projectname* name 'Record'` & `Cannot find *projectname* name 'undefined'` which are both inside the `index.d.ts` file.

while googling for a fix for those errors, I came upon several pages like [**this one**](https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/issues/430) and [**this one**](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18724) to name a few, but to no avail.

I'm so confused and I can't find a solution to the `Cannot find *projectname* name 'Record'` & `Cannot find *projectname* name 'undefined'` errors.

---

**EDIT**

also I tried to simply take out the line which was giving the error: `[name: string]: (BaseModifier & Record<string, any>) | undefined;` but that just gave me an `System.OutOfMemoryException`.

---

Does anybody know what I should do to resolve this problem?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer. You need to update Typescript to the lastest.

[Build error "Cannot find name 'Record'" with bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564979/build-error-cannot-find-name-record-with-bootstrap-4)

Comment: I've updated the TypeScript to 2.9.2 , but the problem exists yet!

Comment: Oh, this link helps: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Updating-TypeScript-in-Visual-Studio-2017